# Trying to make an Editbox move up and down with a button click

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

hi i'm trying to make an editbox move down from 300 by 30 when a button is clicked, and upon clicking the same button again, make editbox move back up by 30 to its original position. However when i click the button ive made it just moves up by 30 each time, where am i going wrong? here is my code,

```
procedure TfrmProject.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  if Edit1.Top = 300 then 
    Edit1.Top := Edit1.Top + 30 else 
    Edit1.Top := Edit1.Top - 30;    
end;
```

EDIT: I have realised that due to my form being long and having a vertical scrollbar, the property Top of the editbox changes in response to where i am on the form, i.e if i'm at the top of my form the Top property of the edit box increases (the editbox is near the bottom of the form), therefore my new question is how could i ensure the editbox only moves between 2 fixed points, as following the recent suggestions the edit box moves between two points with a 30 distance between them, but their positions on the form change.

Comment: sorry that i posted the code oddly, new to the site

Comment: Strange, it works just fine for me...

Comment: My guess is that it never was positioned at position 300 in the first place. Probably it's at 301 or 302, or something similar. That would make the edit box move upwards each time you click the button.

Comment: The object inspector for the Edit box in the property Top says 300, which i set it too.

Comment: It turns out that the Property Top changes due to the fact that my form is long and has a scrollbar, therefore scrolling up and down changes the distance of the editbox to the top, however i need code which will allow the movement of the edit box between two fixed points which do not change regardless of my positioning on the form

Comment: Is the Edit positioned directly on the form? Or is it on a TPanel or other container? Is your goal to keep the edit control a certain distance above the bottom edge of the visible part of the window? This really should now be a new (separate) question with more info about what you're asking now.

Comment: if your Edit1 is anchored on the bottom, the top property will change if you resize your form. Anchor on top and it won't.

Comment: It's been 14 hours since you asked your question, so maybe you've figured this out, but I've provided a solution below for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works perfectly fine for me.

Create a new Delphi VCL Forms Application

Drop a TEdit and a TButton on the new form. Set the `Top' property of each to`50`using the`Object Inspector`.

Double-click `Button1`, and paste the following code to replace the newly generated `TForm1.Button1Click` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Edit1.Top = 50 then
    Edit1.Top := Edit1.Top + 30
  else
    Edit1.Top := 50;
end;
```

Run the application. Repeatedly clicking `Button1` makes `Edit1` move up and down from `50` to `80`.

This means your comparison is wrong. Set the `Button1.Top` explicitly to the original coordinate (`300` in your code) instead of reducing by `30`.

Comment: I have worked out the problem which makes this answer not what i need, however i still dont know how to solve it. the Property Top changes due to the fact that my form is long and has a scrollbar, therefore scrolling up and down changes the distance of the editbox to the top, but i need code which will allow the movement of the edit box between two fixed points which do not change.

Comment: @user1277240 - I'm sorry; what you're asking now isn't clear, and appears to be a totally different question than the one asked above. (I don't know what the new question is, though; your comment is confusing.) My answer here is based on the question you asked here.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the response and it is true that this is now a slightly different question, i have therefore accepted your original answer. However my new question comes as a result of this code not achieving what i need (although i didn't state it in the original question). The code you suggested works if the form has no verticalscrollbar because the button.top always remains the same and therefore the edit box moves up and down between 2 fixed points (50 and  80). However when the form has a verticalscrollbar the value for button.top changes depending on your viewing position on the page.

Comment: You should ask a separate question, then. You need to provide a lot more information, and that changes the question totally. For instance, I added a comment asking about the parent of the edit above. Is it on the form itself? Is it on a panel or other container instead? What content is on the form that makes it so large it has scrollbars? The answer to your question will vary based on the form's actual layout, and (as I said) that makes it a totally different question.

Answer (score 2):

Then the original setting of the `Top` property was not 300. Or the movement is not (fully) allowed due to constraint, align or anchor settings of the edit control or those of adjacent controls.

Possible solutions:

- **When Top should always be 300:**

  Set `Edit1.Top` to 300. And make sure there is movement possible.
- **When 299 < Top < 330:**

  Change the comparison to:

  ```
  if Edit1.Top < 330 then
  ```
- **When Top should remain undesided:**

  Use the `Tag` property of the edit control (or a private variable, or...) to remember in which direction it has to move:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  const
    MoveNorth = 0;
    MoveSouth = 1;
  begin
    if Edit1.Tag = MoveNorth then
      Edit1.Top := Edit1.Top + 30 else
      Edit1.Top := Edit1.Top - 30;
    if Edit1.Tag = MoveNorth then
      Edit1.Tag := MoveSouth else
      Edit1.Tag := MoveNorth;
  end;
  ```
- **Use [Ken's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796447/757830)**.

Comment: the original setting for Top is definitely 300, infact the code was working when i first tested it but now doesn't even though i can't see what could have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick for you.

Place a label with no caption on the form with the Top property set to 0 and the anchors set to [akLeft, akTop]. Use that label as a place holder, so you always know where the top of the form is. When it's off the screen at the top from scrolling, the Top property will actually become negative.

Now, use the label's Top property as your starting point, so to put the edit box at 300 pixels from the top:

```
Edit1.Top := Label1.Top + 300;
```

That's the easy way. I figure the proper way is to use the position of the vertical scroll bar like this:

```
Edit1.Top := 300 - Self.VertScrollBar.Position;
```